# jpg file difference : from wireshark tcp stream and from a C++ socket

Tags: tcp, jpeg, wireshark, mjpeg, content-length

I'm trying to record a jpeg image sent by an Ethernet camera in a mjpg stream.
The image I obtain with my Borland C++ application (VSPCIP) looks identical in Notepad++ to the tcp stream saved from the application Wireshark (except for the number of characters : 15540 in my file, and 15342 in the wireshark file, whereas the jpeg content-length is announced to be 15342).
That is to say that I have 198 non-displayable characters more than expected but both files have 247 lines.

Here are the two files :
http://demo.ovh.com/fr/a61295d39f963998ba1244da2f55a27d/

Which tool could I use (in Notepad++ (I tried to display in UTF8 or ANSI : files still match whereas they don't have the same number of characters) or another editor) to view the non-displayable characters ?

Comment: In your program, do you open the file in binary or text mode?

Comment: In my program, I store the byte from the TCP stream to a :
BYTE * ImageFrame = new BYTE [ContentLength];

and to create a file (just to view the data of the BYTE*) I use :

std::ofstream * mpofs;
mpofs = new std::ofstream("out.jpg");
for(int i=0;i<ContentLength;i++) *mpofs <<ImageFrame[i];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::ofstream` by default opens the file in text mode, which means it might translate newline characters (`'\n'` binary 0x0a) into a carriage-return/newline sequence (`"\r\n"`, binary 0x0d and 0x0a).

Open the output file in binary mode and it will most likely solve your problem:

```
std::ofstream os("filename", ios_base::out | ios_base::binary);
```

Comment: ok tak, std::ios_base helped : I have a good jpg image, my problem is perhaps somewhere else : I have sometimes incomplete frames (though I used a mutex to avoid reading the byte * while I fill it, my problem so must be in the way I decode the tcp stream, I search this way and tell further). Thanks

Comment: Ok I found an "incomplete jpeg frame" : it has 21690 characters (for a 640x480 jpeg image) and among them there is a string of 5045 following characters which have the value "NUL" (displayed as NUL in Notepad++).
Two things :
- I would first like to remove these corrupted frame
- it would be good to understand in the TCP "readbyte" why it adds this string

Comment: I will move this to another question in fact.

Comment: Moved here :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853460/unwanted-nul-characters-string-after-reading-bytes-of-a-mjpg-tcp-stream